# Need Indexing on derived column of MySql for pagination

Tags: mysql, laravel, indexing, view, phpmyadmin

Database Used: Xampp PhpmyAdmin

I have bunch of records, In that one calculative column say 'goal' is there.

So,

```
SELECT *,(x *100/y) AS goal FROM temp_table HAVING (`goal` >= 0) ORDER BY goal DESC LIMIT 0,10;

SELECT *,(x *100/y) AS goal FROM temp_table HAVING (`goal` >= 0) ORDER BY goal DESC LIMIT 10,10;
```

As a result of both the above query, duplicate entries are fetched, like data on page 1 is getting repeated in rest pages.

As per research I come to know that pagination works on INDEXING and goal field is a non-indexed column.

Expected Result:
No duplication should be there in any pages.

So let me know how can i achieve this.

I had created view but in that as well indexing issue arise.

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Do the results have the same value for "goal" on the first few pages? If they have, you might want to order it by something else after "goal". Otherwise you will need to provide an example (http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a good way to share the example).

Comment: @Vatev Thanks for your quick reply. Yes "goal" having same value for different pages.

Comment: Well, you will need to order it by "goal" and something else. E.g.: `ORDER BY goal DESC, id ASC`.